# I am having problem to calculating % on base of subtotal value in Matrix in SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

I am having problem to calculate the % value on the base of subtotal per each row and in the column.

As you may see from the snap shot# 1, I am unable to calculate the percentage value basing upon the sub-total value (i.e. from the 1st row).
[image]

And this is how i want to show my output as shown below snapshot.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for the above question calculating the percentage based on the subtotal for inscope values.

=FormatPercent(Sum(Fields!StartingInventory.Value)/Fields!Sum_StartingInventory.Value,1)